# I encountered terminal process error why trying to run python script?

Tags: javascript, python, django, visual-studio-code, ide

i'm currently trying to run my python script for my django project, but i encounter this error in my vscode IDE. how can i resolve this? How can i also locate legacy on my cmd.exe windows 7[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBnPX.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Instead [edit] your question and include your code as a [mcve] so that we can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Very sorry for being late.

[The terminal process terminated with exit code: 4294901760](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100366)

> If you're on Windows 10 1809 (build 17763) or below, the issue is
> related to the legacy "winpty" backend. Upgrading to Windows 1903
> (build 18362) will move you onto the new "conpty" backend that is
> built by Microsoft and could fix your problem.

You can try to switch the terminal from PowerShell to CMD:

Open Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), type in `Terminal: Select Default Profile`.

Or

You can add this to the settings.json file directly:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",

"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell",
      "path": [
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
      ],

      "args": ["-NoLogo"]
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
  },
```